# Twemcache exceeds max memory setting

Tags: caching, memory, memory-leaks, memcached

I started twemcache with "twemcache -d -m 20". It should consume no more than 20 MB.
But according to test, it keeps consuming more memory with "set" then "get".

```
    import memcache
    mc = memcache.Client(['localhost:11211'])
    i = 0
    while True:
      i+=1
      key = value = str(i)
      mc.set(key, value)
      mc.get(key)
```

I found this because I had a service with -m 4000 and exceeded the cap, and finally killed by os. Anyone know how I can avoid? Thanks in advance.

Comment: start memcached with correct configuration? twemcache is just a proxy, it doesn't store data itself nor does it configure running memcached instances

Comment: Thanks, the bug is fixed in 2.5.3 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of twemcache, fixed in 2.5.3 release.
https://github.com/twitter/twemcache/issues/17